# Calculating growth in wbdata (World Bank). Can Pandas copy indicator data per country from 2008 into a new column in the same country's 2018 row?

Tags: pandas

I'm stumped on how to take indicator data from ten-year-old data (2008) and add it to a new field in the 2018 record - per country.

I use the new column to next calculate 10-year growth from 2008 to 2018.

World Bank indicator data downloads are typically pandas dataframes with:

```
index (0,1,2,3 ...)
date (string - typically 2018-01-01, 2017-01-01, ...)
country (string - typically Canada, United States, etc. there are 300 countries and regions)
indicator (float - each file has one indicator and can be 15,000+- lines)
```

I want to add a new column and add the 10-year, 20-year growth in each indicator value

df['10_year_old_value']=df['country'.'date'+10_y].map(str)

```
pd.labels = ( date, country, indicator, 10yr_old_value )
pd.values = 2018-01-01, Canada, 100.02, 80.123
            2017-01-01, Canada, 99.143, 79.876
            2016-01-01, Canada, 98.076,
            ...
            2008-01-01, Canada, 80.123,
            2007-01-01, Canada, 79.876, 
            ...
            2018-01-01, United States, 1000.02, 800.123
            2017-01-01, United States, 990.143, 790.876
            2016-01-01, United States, 980.076,
            ...
            2008-01-01, United States, 800.123,
            2007-01-01, United States, 790.876,
```

[image]
With this data, I can then create a 10-year-growth column ...

df['10-year-growth'] = df['Indicator']- df['10_year_old_value']

Another consideration is that 10-year or 20-year old data is not always available, so the code has to look up or down two or three years (rows) for a data value (using a while not null loop - or similar)

Answer (score 0):

I worked through a solution to create the Change values, posted here for others using World Bank data. These stats are used to create Transition Economics charts (http://transitioneconomics.info). A library of TEPs are kept at http://csq1.org/WAOH

```
                # Step 1 - Create a pivot view of WB Data

                table = df2.pivot(index='country', columns='date', values= 'NE.EXP.GNFS.ZS' ).reset_index()

                # Determine most recent year data was recorded - as a starting point

                rws, cols = table.shape
                cols=cols-1
                firstcol=0
                firstdatacol = np.empty(rws, dtype=int)
                mostrecentvalue = np.empty(rws, dtype=float)
                yr10val = np.empty(rws, dtype=float)
                yr20val = np.empty(rws, dtype=float)

                for i in range(rws): 
                    # print(rws, i)
                    if not pd.isna(table.iat[i,cols]): 
                        firstdatacol[i] = cols
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,cols-1]): 
                        firstdatacol[i] = cols-1
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,cols-2]): 
                        firstdatacol[i] = cols-2
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,cols-3]):
                        firstdatacol[i] = cols-3
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,cols-4]):
                        firstdatacol[i] = cols-4
                    else: 
                        firstdatacol[i] = 0
                    if firstdatacol[i] == 0:
                        mostrecentvalue[i] = np.nan
                    else:
                        first_col = firstdatacol[i]
                        mostrecentvalue[i] = table.iat[i,first_col]

                # Step 2 - Subtract most recent data from 10-year-old values. If no data is available 10 years ago, search for data in years close to it (8 to 14 years in this example) and use that value.

                for i in range(rws): 
                    first_col = firstdatacol[i]
                    if not pd.isna(table.iat[i, first_col-10]):
                        yr10val[i]= table.iat[i, first_col-10]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i, first_col-9]):
                        yr10val[i]= table.iat[i, first_col-9]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i, first_col-8]):
                        yr10val[i]= table.iat[i, first_col-8]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i, first_col-11]):
                        yr10val[i]= table.iat[i, first_col-11]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,first_col-12]):
                        yr10val[i]= table.iat[i, first_col-12]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i, first_col-13]):
                        yr10val[i]= table.iat[i, first_col-13]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i, first_col-14]):
                        yr10val[i]= table.iat[i, first_col-14]
                    else: 
                        yr10val[i] = np.nan

                yr10change = mostrecentvalue - yr10val

                # Step 3 - Do the same for 20-year-old data

                for i in range(rws): 
                    first_col = firstdatacol[i]
                    if not pd.isna(table.iat[i,first_col-20]):
                        yr20val[i]= table.iat[i,first_col-20]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,first_col-19]): 
                        yr20val[i]= table.iat[i,first_col-19]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,first_col-21]): 
                        yr20val[i]= table.iat[i,first_col-21]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,first_col-18]): 
                        yr20val[i]= table.iat[i,first_col-18]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,first_col-22]): 
                        yr20val[i]= table.iat[i,first_col-22]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,first_col-23]): 
                        yr20val[i]= table.iat[i,first_col-23]
                    elif not pd.isna(table.iat[i,first_col-24]): 
                        yr20val[i]= table.iat[i,first_col-24]
                    else: 
                        yr20val[i] = np.nan

                yr20change = mostrecentvalue - yr20val

                # Insert table columns for 10-year and 20-year Change in Indicator Values

                table.insert(1, 'chg_10yr', yr10change)
                table.insert(2, 'chg_20yr', yr20change)
```